# Нужна помощь с jquery inputmask (decimal)!

Tags: jquery, inputmask

Всем привет! Проблема такая: сейчас в inputmask в свойстве "radixPoint" стоит значение ",". И когда ввожу в инпуте точку или запятую, то показывает запятую - окей. Но когда меняю значение radixPoint на ".", то при нажатии в инпуте на точку - ставит точку, а при нажатии на запятую - ничего не происходит(для глаза). Нужно, чтобы когда нажимаешь на точку или запятую, показывалась только точка на фронте.

На данный момент код со всеми мудрениями выглядит так:

```
$('[name=sum]').inputmask({
    alias: "decimal",
    rightAlign: false,
    groupSeparator: " ",
    radixPoint: ".",
    autoGroup: true,
    integerDigits: 13,
    digitsOptional: true,
    digits: 2,
    allowPlus: false,
    allowMinus: false,
    onKeyDown: function () {
        //console.log(arguments, this);
        if (event.which === 188) {
            console.log(event);
            event.preventDefault();
            event.key = ".";
            event.which = 190;
            event.keyCode = 190;
        }
    },
    onUnMask: function(maskedValue, unmaskedValue, opts) {
        var value = String(unmaskedValue)
            .replace(RegExp(opts.radixPoint), '.')
            .replace(RegExp(opts.groupSeparator), '');
        return parseFloat(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Не секу в `inputmask'e`
Но вот небольшая регулярка под подобную маску:

```js
$(document).on('input', '[name=sum]', function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = val
    .replace(/\,/g,'.')
    .replace(/(\.)+?(.*)(\.)/,'$1$2')
    .replace(/([^,.\d])|([,.](?=[,.]))|(^\D)/g,'')
    .replace(/([,.]\d{2})(\d)/,'$1');
  $(this).val(val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='sum'/>
```

*(Если имеются регулярки не такие монструозные и не в 4 реплейса, я с удовольствием выслушаю)*

`replace(/\,/g,'.') - заменяем все запятые на точки`

```
replace(/
    ([^,.\d])| - Ищем любой символ, кроме `,` `.` или цифры
    (\.(?=\.))| - либо ищем любую точку, после которой уже стоит точка, 
                  не(!) включая следующую, иначе при замене,
                  когда пользователь поставит вторую точку, то обе схлопнутся
    (\.(?=(.*\.))) - Т.к. в JS нет lookbehind'a, иными словами
                     мы не можем проверить что было до Выражения
                     без занесения этого в "совпадение", просто заменим предыдущую точку
/g,'')
.replace(/(\.\d{2})(\d)/,'$1') - опять же из-за отсутствия lookbehind`a, просто заменим 3ю цифру после точки на ''
```

Comment: Регулярка то подходит, только изначально inputmask не дает вводить запятую, чтобы она отобразилась пользователю. Это ограничение inputmask на сколько я знаю. Что якобы у них не принято разбивать запятой. Но спасибо

Comment: @alexchep дак а какое поведение то необходимо? Эта регулярка просто запятые преобразует в точки, при этом давая возможность их вводить. Я думал, это и ожидается. Поправь, если ошибся

Comment: Такое поведение и необходимо, но не все так просто.  Inputmask когда вешаешь, то он игнорит запятую(не показывает для клиента. Будто он и не нажимал ее). И вот нужно как-то обойти это. Регулярка, то заменит, но заменять по сути нечего. Нужно сделать, чтобы я хотя бы увидел эту запятую к примеру.

Comment: @alexchep тогда возможно так. А для чего нужны будут запятые? Они дублируют значение точек(разделитель десятичных долей числа) или делят число по тысячным разрядам?

Comment: В общем..в чем смысл.  Пользователь должен вводить на клаве хоть точку, хоть запятую, но должен получить точку на клиенте. Inputmask блочит запятую(при нажатии н запятую, ничего не видно, но в консоли естественно нажатую запятую видно(ее событие)). Думаю нужно двигаться в сторону событий inputmask'а.

Comment: @alexchep дак первоначальный вариант так и делал

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('[name=sum]').inputmask({
    alias: "decimal",
    rightAlign: false,
    groupSeparator: " ",
    radixPoint: ",",
    autoGroup: true,
    integerDigits: 13,
    digitsOptional: true,
    digits: 2,
    allowPlus: false,
    allowMinus: false,
    onBeforeWrite: function (event, buffer, caretPos, opts) {
        if (buffer.indexOf(',') != -1) {
            buffer[buffer.indexOf(',')] = '.';
        }
    }
});
```